# Where are the assemblies to interact with Sql Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I am running Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate and  SQL Server 2008 R2 Nov 2009 CTP. However, I cannot find the .dlls for Sql Server (So that I can add tables, get the databases collection, etc). Can anyone tell me where dlls are based?

Thanks

Comment: Did you add the programability bits when installing SQL Server client bits?

Answer (score 1):

If SQL Server is installed on the machine you are running the code on, the assemblies should be there.  Otherwise, they are downloadable from here:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=228DE03F-3B5A-428A-923F-58A033D316E1&displaylang=en

(see SMO, specifically)

On my machine, they are here:

Directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK\Assemblies

07/10/2008  05:10 AM           566,296 Microsoft.SqlServer.Rmo.dll
               1 File(s)        566,296 bytes

Directory of C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.Rmo\10.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91

01/30/2009  02:35 PM           566,296 Microsoft.SqlServer.Rmo.dll
               1 File(s)        566,296 bytes

Answer (score -1):

Sql databases are normally never interacted with on such a level.  All these functions can be preformed by sql queries.  The oddness of your question makes it very hard for me to recommend where to start.  Perhaps look at ADO and how to send queries to a database.  Then look into sql syntax for modifying tables

Comment: -1, the OP is probably looking for the Smo dlls, which are perfectly existing

Comment: Yeah, I mean the .dlls so I can interact from C#.